# Are quotients by ideals in polynomial rings preserved by affine transformations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Particularly, if we consider $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ for some $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, then it seems that for constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ $\mathbb{R}/\langle p(ax + b) \rangle \cong \mathbb{R}/\langle p(x) \rangle$. For a simple example, if $p(x) = x^2 + 1$, $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}$, and the same must hold for $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle p(ax + b) \rangle$, since $p(x+1)$ is still an irreducible polynomial of order 2.

Does this hold in general for $\mathbb{R}[x]$? What about in other contexts such as $R[x]$ or even $R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$?

Comment: Are you saying that on $k[x]$, $k$ a field (say), with $a$ and $b\in k$, $$p(x) \mapsto p(ax + b)$$ is NOT a ring homomorphism?

Comment: Oh... I see my mistake. I was mapping elements of the base ring, not the polynomials themselves. Yes, that was a confusion on my part.

Comment: I think that is probably the issue... Suppose $A$ is a ring, and $\lambda$ a ring auto of $A$ (so invertible), and $I$ an ideal. Then $\lambda$ induces an iso of rings $$A/ I \to A /\lambda (I).$$ Here, if $a$ is non-zero (as in your question), the affine trans gives rise to an auto of the poly ring.